# Is it proper to run a Docker image on a host with a different system?

Tags: docker

E.g. run a Ubuntu image on a CentOS host, or vice versa. Can I get a real Ubuntu environment inside the image even on a CentOS host?

Comment: I think that it would be technically possible if both operating systems could use an identical kernel. In a practical sense, I would say that it's not possible in any useful, maintainable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ubuntu image on a CentOS host, or vice versa

Yes, as long as the kernel is recent enough to support docker.
The container does not see the OS and its dynamic libraries, it only depends on system call to the kernel.

> Can I get a real Ubuntu environment inside the image even on a CentOS host?

"real"? Generally, it is a trimmed version of Ubuntu, without the X11 layer.
But other than that, yes.